# Why is const used in function declarations

Tags: c

I am new to C, and by looking to the declaration of fopen() function:

```
FILE *fopen(const char *filename, const char *mode)
```

I noticed the use of "const" before the two parameters, as far as I know about constants in C, they are used only in variables, arrays, etc, that you do not want to have their value changed during the execution of the program, since I always pass a value to fopen() function, wouldn't these two "const" trow an error (since "const" should not let the user give a new value to a variable, so it should not let you give a value to "const char *filename" and "const char *mode")?

Comment: Declaring `const` arguments means basically "I promise not to modify these".

Comment: Do you mean modify as giving a new value (storing a new value inside of them)?

Comment: There is no "throwing" an error, since that would be at runtime. Adding `const` does not prevent a system from cheating. It is a hint for the compiler. If a `const char *` is passed to a function that accepts `char *` that may indicate undesired behaviour, and the compiler can then warn about it.

Comment: I mean modifying as in changing anything at the memory location that pointer indicates. You *promise* not to. The compiler can optimize accordingly.